# When I click the submit button on my php form, I get HTTP ERROR 500. On localhost works fine

Tags: php, server

I started experimenting something with php and databases. When I run this on localhost it works perfectly. The info gets written in the database and everything is fine. When I transfer it to my server and run the script I get HTTP ERROR 500. Also, nothing gets written in the database table.
I changed the database info to my server's database. Could something be wrong with my server configuration? Or is it the code?
[Browser error pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KpVpa.png)

Here is the code: **(create-account.php)**

```
 <?php
include('classes/db.php');

if (isset($_POST['createaccount'])) {
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];

    DB::query('INSERT INTO users VALUES (\'\', :username, :password, :email)', array(':username'=>$username, ':password'=>$password, ':email'=>$email));
    echo "bravo";
}

?>


<h1>Register</h1>
<form action="create-account.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="username" value="" placeholder="Username ...">

    <input type="password" name="password" value="" placeholder="Password ...">

    <input type="email" name="email" value="" placeholder="someone@somesite.com">

    <input type="submit" name="createaccount" value="Create Account">

</form>
```

**Here is the connection and query code (db.php):**

```
    <?php 

class db {
    private static function connect() {
        $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=ip;dbname=SocialNetwork;charset=utf8', 'root', 'password');
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        return $pdo;
    }

    public static function query($query, $params = array()) {
        $statement = self::connect()->prepare($query);
        $statement->execute($params);
        //  $data = $statement->fetchAll();
        //  return $data;
    }
}

?>
```

Here is the last error from the log, if that helps too

```
[Fri May 05 13:48:33.828431 2017] [:error] [pid 16509] [client95.176.134.34:53373] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught PDOException:SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused in/var/www/html/classes/db.php:5\nStack trace:\n#0 /var/www/html/classes/db.php(5): PDO->__construct('mysql:host=207....', 'root', 'password')\n#1 /var/www/html/classes/db.php(11): db::connect()\n#2 /var/www/html/create-account.php(9): db::query('INSERT INTO use...', Array)\n#3 {main}\n  thrown in /var/www/html/classes/db.php on line 5, referer: http://ip/create-account.php
```

Comment: Always check the server error logs when you get a 500 error. That error covers a multitude of errors and no guidance without looking at the logs.

Comment: i guess you are a developer. You can say stuff like its not working. There is something called `debugging` and we wont do that for you.

Comment: The connection is refused. Make sure there's no firewalls on the database server, that and that the user/password/IP combination exists as a user in the database.

Comment: aynber's response is on the right track.  Connection refused.  Chase that thread.